# Whats the difference between a destination vc and a source vc?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

im trying to learn how to perform custom segues so i can have a game menu, and when i searched on the web it seems that you have to make a custom segue class, and override `-(void) perform` and in that method you have to specify a made up destination vc and a source vc. and establish its location and stuff. This was the one of the code things i saw on the internet.

```
@implementation FromTopReplaceSegue
-(void)perform{
    UIViewController *dst = [self destinationViewController];
    UIViewController *src = [self sourceViewController];
    [dst viewWillAppear:NO];
    [dst viewDidAppear:NO];


    [src.view addSubview:dst.view];

    CGRect original = dst.view.frame;

    dst.view.frame = CGRectMake(dst.view.frame.origin.x, 0-dst.view.frame.size.height, dst.view.frame.size.width, dst.view.frame.size.height);

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    dst.view.frame = CGRectMake(original.origin.x, original.origin.y, original.size.height, original.size.width);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self performSelector:@selector(animationDone:) withObject:dst afterDelay:0.2f];
}
- (void)animationDone:(id)vc{
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController*)vc;
    UINavigationController *nav = [[self sourceViewController] navigationController];
    [nav popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [nav pushViewController:dst animated:NO];

}
@end
```

i guess this is supposed to make a segue that appears from the top going down or something. but i have a few questions like, what is a source and dest vc, and also in the part where the code says `dst.view.fram=CGRectMake(dst.view.frame.origin.x, 0-dst.view.frame.size.height,`

what the heck is that 0 there, and shouldnt that be `dst.view.frame.origin.y` ?

well, anyways i wired this up and created a push segue from a button, but when i did this the segue only came to about 3/4 down from the top of the screen, and the bottom 1/4 was showing the bottom of my root view. and also when i tried pressing a button on my new vc after the segue the program crashes.

Any Info would help Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those things that aren't fully explained it looks like. Judging from your code, it looks like the "source view controller" is the root view controller(or parent view controller) and the "destination view controller" is the DetailViewController(or the child view controller).

Not sure if this confuses you more. Anyways, the parent/root view controller is the main view controller and it handles displaying of child view controllers. What I find interesting is that the creator subclassed the view of another class rather than presenting it.

Now 0 - self.view.frame.size.height = -320 on the y axis. Think of your main view as a piece of paper and think of the child view as a second piece of paper. Imagine placing the two pieces of paper one above the other(not on top.) The screen will only display the bottom piece of paper until you animate the "paper above it" down. Basically, he plans to animate from the top rather than the bottom(I guess I answered my own curiosity.)